# How to hide bottom navigation when we navigate to a child route on `ShellRoute`?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I am trying to create the following navigation:

```
|_ShellRoute
  |_GoRoute /a (needs bottomNav)
    |_GoRoute /a/nested/:id (does not need bottomNav)
  |_GoRoute /b (needs bottomNav)
  |_GoRoute /c (needs bottomNav)
```

However when I navigate to `/a/nested/1` the bottom navigation still shows.

My route code (I am using type safe routes, but I think this stills applies to "normal" go_router):

```dart
final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: $appRoutes,
  initialLocation: '/a',
  navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
);

final shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

@TypedShellRoute<BottomShellRoute>(routes: [
  TypedGoRoute<ARoute>(path: '/a', routes: [
    TypedGoRoute<ANestedRoute>(path: 'nested/:id'),
  ]),
  TypedGoRoute<BRoute>(path: '/b'),
  TypedGoRoute<CRoute>(path: '/c'),
])
class BottomShellRoute extends ShellRouteData {
  const BottomShellRoute();

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> $navigatorKey = shellNavigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget navigator) => BottomShellScreen(
        location: state.location,
        child: navigator,
      );
}
```

Any idea how to make this route not show the bottom navigation?

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this would be to "hide" the bottom nav bar on certain routes. Meaning that the bottom nav bar is going to *always* be in the widget tree, just **hidden** from view.

This logic would live within the `BottomShellScreen` widget's build method.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (location == '/a/nested/:id'){
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
   }

   return ...;
}
```

Comment: My workaround was similar. I made a function that checks if we are on the first navigation level (I want to hide the bottom navigation for all screens except for the first level). However this seems a workaround, but maybe it's the correct answer. If there is no better approach to achieve this, I will mark this as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `go_router`, and in my case I just have to set `parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey` on the nested route.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @[mrgnhnt96](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76203400/18496393) solution my work around to this is as follows

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.uri == '/a/nested/:id'){
  return const SizedBox.shrink();
}

return ...;
}
```

`GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.uri` is used since `value.location` is depricated currently.

and in the child page

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
    if (!didPop) {
      GoRouter.of(context).goNamed(<routeName>);
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have previously answered at another question on how to hide bottom navigation bar on ShellRoute for "normal" GoRoute.
[How to hide BottomNavigationBar in specific routes using GoRouter in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76783122/how-to-hide-bottomnavigationbar-in-specific-routes-using-gorouter-in-flutter/76809709#76809709)
It might be a different for TypedGoRoute, but if you can use the normal one, my answer would definitely help you. I can try to find a solution for TypedGoRoute if you prefer that.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired behavior where the bottom navigation is not shown when navigating to `/a/nested/:id`, you can use nested navigators. In your code, it looks like you're using `GoRouter` for navigation. You can create a nested navigator for the `/a` route that excludes the bottom navigation. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: $appRoutes,
  initialLocation: '/a',
  navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
);

final shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

@TypedShellRoute<BottomShellRoute>(routes: [
  TypedGoRoute<ARoute>(path: '/a', builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    // Create a nested navigator for /a route
    final aNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

    return Navigator(
      key: aNavigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == '/a') {
          // Show the ARoute when /a is navigated to
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ARoute());
        } else if (settings.name == '/a/nested/:id') {
          // Show the ANestedRoute when /a/nested/:id is navigated to
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ANestedRoute());
        }
        return null; // Return null for other routes
      },
    );
  }),
  TypedGoRoute<BRoute>(path: '/b'),
  TypedGoRoute<CRoute>(path: '/c'),
])
class BottomShellRoute extends ShellRouteData {
  const BottomShellRoute();

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> $navigatorKey = shellNavigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget navigator) => BottomShellScreen(
        location: state.location,
        child: navigator,
      );
}
```

In this modified code:

1. We create a nested navigator, `aNavigatorKey`, for the `/a` route within the `TypedGoRoute<ARoute>`.
2. We use the Navigator widget with this `aNavigatorKey` to manage the navigation for the `/a` route and its nested routes.
3. Inside the `onGenerateRoute` callback of the Navigator, we define how to build the widgets for each route, including `/a` and `/a/nested/:id`. You can customize these builders as needed.

By implementing nested navigation in this way, the `/a/nested/:id` route will be managed separately from the bottom navigation, and you won't see the bottom navigation when navigating to `/a/nested/:id`.